# Does Blender have a materials file?

Tags: texturing, materials

I was going to add skin textures and others to my available materials
in Blender but cant find a file in the Blender files where these are kept.

Comment: All of the information (except for the images used as textures unless you "pack" them) is part of the .blend file. To access information within the file you would need to append or link a file. Read: [How to import Downloaded Materials/Files?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63018) There is an addon to create material libraries: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/106566. To make the materials available on startup add the materials to the default scene. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64610/how-to-save-material-library

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63018/how-to-import-downloaded-materials-files